# Discordbot read DM messages and log them

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to read DM messages only and send them to a discord channel, but my code spam the message infinitely, spamming 5 times and then it pauses for a few seconds then spam again, also the bot don't read only DM messages and reads also guild messages so if I send anything in the guild it spams the content.

What do I want?
If someone sends 'Hello!' (message content) to the bot in DM, the bot needs to send 'Hello!' (message content) to the specified channel (logs channel).

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");  
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents:['DIRECT_MESSAGES'],
partials: ['MESSAGE'] });


client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot Online!'); //bot successfully logged in

});


  client.on('message', async (message) => {
    await client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID').send(message.content);
    console.log(message.content); //log messages
    return;
});
// Authorizing
client.login('LOGIN');
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that when the bot sends the message to the log channel. It also triggers the `message` event again. To avoid this simply add

```js
if(message.author.bot) return;
```

You code would look like

```js
  client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    await client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID').send(message.content);
    console.log(message.content); //log messages
    return;
});
```

#### If you only want to get direct messages

You can use

```js
if(message.guild) return;
```

```js
  client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if(message.guild) return;
    await client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID').send(message.content);
    console.log(message.content); //log messages
    return;
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks and how do I tell the bot to read only the DM messages

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem @Ecstasyyy.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if the message comes from a guild should stop this. Return early if `message.guild` is truthy (in DM `message.guild` is `null` which is a falsey value)

```js
if (message.guild) return;
```

You would put this at the top of the event callback so that nothing runs if it's in a guild

Comment: How do I set this as true because I want the bot to log all DM messages from another bot   ` if(message.author.bot) return;`

Comment: It should already log them - if you have that line already remove it if you want bot messages

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain well.. I want the bot to read only messages sent by another bots, to not read messages sent by normal users

Comment: Using the logical NOT operator (`!`) do this: `if(!message.author.bot) return;`

Comment: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user -> I'm getting this error while trying to send message from a bot to another bot, any fix?

Comment: Actually, I don't think bots can send messages to other bots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238333/discussion-between-ecstasyyy-and-mrmythical).

Answer (score 0):

For Discord.js v13 use the CHANNEL partial as well, i hope that works

Btw

```js
if (message.channel.type != "DM") return;
```